# Server mapping without url

Tags: java, servlets, url-rewriting, web.xml

I have a custom router and `forward` requests to specified servlets after some processes. So servlets are actually private in web.xml but router itself.

Is it possible to **not** set url-pattern for a servlet and make it unaccessible from web?
Currently i'm using a big hash as url-pattern and checking some flags which don't exist in direct requests.

Comment: did you tried mapping servlet to something like `/WEB-INF/servletName`? just a supposition, never tried myself.

Comment: If you do not set a servlet url pattern it is going to be hard to forward requests to it. Do these other servlets have to be servlets? Can they be action classes that just do the action you want them to without having to get the request as a servlet?

Comment: @MicheleMariotti Worked great! Thanks. It returns 404 without passing request to servlets.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian You are right. Servlet without url-pattern is not actually a servlet. I'm just using web.xml structure (key - servlet class) to find servlet class. I'm using web.xml just as a map and the only reason that i do not use a simple map (e.g. HashMap<String, String>) is web.xml doesn't allow wrong class names and refactoring classes will update it. So if you know a strong map for my purpose, i appreciate.

Comment: @AHHP Wouldn't a HashMap<String, Class> do the trick then?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian It's great. It is ok to have a class containing about 100 class imports (for filling the hashmap)?

Comment: @AHHP Not quite sure I understand that last question, but if you are asking if it is ok to have about 100 key-value mappings in the HashMap, that shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian a HashMap<String, Class> containing 100 items means there are at least 100 class imports (one import per each Class entry in hashmap). So is it ok to have a router (heavy-traffic) class which is linked to about 100 classes?

Comment: @AHHP That is hard to tell since I do not understand your entire scenario (you're the expert in that). It is also about object instantiation of your classes if you do that on every request. If you are worried about performance I would suggest you do some kind of performance test comparing the two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in answer to your **very nice** comment, here you are:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/WEB-INF/test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        resp.getWriter().println("helloooooooooooo");
    }

}
```

and

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/router")
public class Router extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

and this works **perfectly**:

[image: screenshot]

while test servlet is not accessible

[image: screenshot2]

however, i suggest you to be nicer with people trying to help you :)

Comment: Hahaha...You misunderstood Michele! I tested it and got 404 and it was what i wanted (assign URL which is not accessible). So your solution worked greatly and i appreciated in my previous comment.

Comment: O.o i'm so sorry!! i thought you were sarcastic! just can't get [sarcastaball](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlv6BrrxD_4) out of my head :D

Answer (score 1):

Since youre classes are not really used as Servlets I would suggest that they are not implemented as servlets. Move away from mapping in your `web.xml` and use a `HasMap<String, Class>` instead for the mapping.